# How can i get this id?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I did't want to make it key and value , I have tried a lot to find a solution, but I can't

[image]

And this my code when I tried to get it by key and value

```
mFriendID = (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("friends").child(current_user).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            fri_id = dataSnapshot.child("fri_id").getValue().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: explain clearly what is the error you are facing?

Comment: Please add your database strucure and indicate the exact id that you want to get.

Comment: Please show the code inserting values

Answer (score 0):

To get the highlighted key, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("friends").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Be aware that this effectively downloads ALL data under `friends`.  I don't recommend doing this when only one child is required.  This sort of strategy doesn't scale, and unnecessarily costs developers time and money, when some other solution should be used.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi Doug and thanks for your comment but why do you say "this effectively downloads ALL data under `friends`"? The `uidRef` points only to a single `uid`(which has only one child) and not to the enitre `friends` node, right?

Comment: It has one child on the screen that you see - but what guarantee do you have that there couldn't be more?

Comment: @DougStevenson That's right Doug, there's no guarantee. In this case I'll wait for the OP to provide the code that is using for inserting the values, as also cricket_007 asked in his comment. So having the second id (`PRop ... nAk1`) it will be very easy to get only one child. Thanks!